# Multiple comparisons w/o "als"

Tags: comparison

I am trying to understand the order in the following text.

> In einem Laufwettbewerb beendete Gabi das Rennen in 1 Stunde. Fabian kam in 13 Minuten mehr, Gregor in 8 Minuten weniger an.

It is not clear to me if Gregor finished 8 minutes less than Fabian or 8 minutes less than Gabi.

Shouldn't we use "als" to be more precise or is there something I am missing in the text?

Comment: This sentence is worded clumsily or may not have been written by a native speaker. Where does it originate?

Answer (score 12):

Nein, die Aussage ist auch so eindeutig: Es sind 8 Minuten weniger als Gabi.

Die einzige Begründung die ich geben kann, ist, dass das der Sprachgebrauch ist.

Bezöge sich die Zeit auf den zweiten Genannten, würde die Aussage mehr zu einem Matherätsel, als zu einer Meldung.

> In einem Laufwettbewerb beendete Gabi das Rennen in 1 Stunde. Fabian kam in 13 Minuten mehr, Gregor in 8 Minuten weniger als jener an.

Wenn, dann würde man die Zeiten ja in der Reihenfolge des Eintreffens melden.

> In einem Laufwettbewerb beendete Gabi das Rennen in 1 Stunde. Gregor kam in 5 Minuten mehr an, Fabian noch einmal 8 Minuten später.

Comment: Der Satz ist eine Abkürzung von: `Fabian kam in 13 Minuten mehr an als Gabi, Gregor kam in 8 Minuten weniger an als Gabi`. Ein Rechner würde so reden, aber Menschen finden die Wiederholungen nicht nötig, sparen Energie, und machen es interessanter. The same happens in other languages too.

Answer (score 0):

you are absolutely right. From the context one can only guess who finished first, who came in second and who was the last.

In einem Laufwettbewerb beendete Gabi das Rennen in 1 Stunde. Fabian kam in 13 Minuten mehr, Gregor in 8 Minuten weniger an.

Tis is because there is no connection or relation bewtween the three competitors.
To be sure about the relationship between the three of them you would fill in something like:

In einem Laufwettbewerb beendete Gabi das Rennen in 1 Stunde. Fabian kam in 13 Minuten mehr als sie, Gregor in 8 Minuten weniger als sie an

or

In einem Laufwettbewerb beendete Gabi das Rennen in 1 Stunde. Fabian kam in 13 Minuten mehr als sie, Gregor in 8 Minuten weniger als er an.